# How to run go core library tests with an `internal` import?

Tags: go

I am trying to run the tests in `crypto/tls`. The problem is that every time I try to run tests I [get](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/crypto/tls/common.go#L21):

```
common.go:20:2: use of internal package internal/cpu not allowed
```

This makes sense as `tls` is a package and does not have a local `internal` directory like a normal package.

So my question is how are these test run to get around this restriction?

Comment: With "core library" you mean the standard library? How to do you try to run the tests?

Comment: `go test crypto/tls`? The tests are also run as part of `all.bash`.

Comment: @Volker I clone the `go` repo, `cd` to `src/crypto/tls` and then run `go test -run=Test...`

Comment: @JimB I'll start to looking there. Any idea how the script actually gets around the internal restriction (pwd, GOPATH, test args, etc)

Comment: Users are not expected to run the tests manually, and the scrip runs the tests from the `src` directory, so `go test crypto/tls` is what is expected to work. GOROOT is handled differently than normal packages, and I think you can force them to work within the `tls` directory by setting GOROOT for the test.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so here is the Quick and dirty method to run custom tests in the standard/core library:

1. Compile the core library and compiler:

```
 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 ./all.bash
```

2. Set the GOROOT to the repo and run the test using package names:

```
$GOROOT=$PWD GOBIN=$PWD/bin GOMODCACHE=$PWD/pkg/mod GOPATH=/tmp/gotest ./bin/go test crypto/tls
```